# AngularJS - how to replace colour for a box shadow with ng-style?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I am writing an app with Angular 1.5.

I am trying to put a box shadow on my element with a dynamic colour.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
  <div
    item="item"
    ng-style="{ 'box-shadow': 5px 0px 0px 0px {{ item.colour }} inset; }"
    ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
</div>
```

The browser keeps throwing this error:
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 32-32 [#] in expression [{ 'box-shadow': 5px 0px 0px 0px #800000 inset; }].

item.colour is a string with a hex value in it.

I have also tried this:

```
ng-style="{ 'box-shadow': 5px 0px 0px 0px item.colour inset; }"
```

and it doesn't work either.

How can I write my ng-style expression for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `ng-style` attribute you can write an expression that works very much like javascript, that is, you can concatenate string the same way javascript does.

For example:

```
ng-style="{ 'box-shadow': '5px 0px 0px 0px ' + item.colour + ' inset' }"
```

**UPDATE 1** Working snippet

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="item = { colour: '#800000'}">
  <div class="box" ng-style="{ 'box-shadow': '5px 0px 0px 0px ' + item.colour + ' inset' }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't throw and error but the colour did not show. '#800000'

Comment: @user1261710 I don't know what you mean, but I've updated my answer with a working snippet and it's working. It's an inset red shadow as your example.

Comment: Hi, it was my fault I forgot the spaces in between 0px and colour. It works, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your html in following way:

```
<div
    item="item"
    ng-style="GetBoxShadowStyle(item)"
    ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
</div>
```

and your controller should have a method like following:

```
$scope.GetBoxShadowStyle = function (item) {
   var boxShadowStyleVal = '5px 0px 0px 0px ' + item.colour + ' inset' ;
   return { "box-shadow": boxShadowStyleVal  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```html
<button 
 class="colour"
 *ngFor="let colour of colors"
 [ngClass]="{ 'selected': selectColour === colour }"
 [ngStyle]="{ 'box-shadow': '1px 2px 3px 0px' + colour + ' inset' }"
></button>
```